# Python 3 - Limit amount of nested loops

Tags: python, loops, nested

Not sure if I can explain this well enough, but ill give it a go. I have a loop nested inside of another loop for example:

```
for a in A: 
    #do stuff
    for b in B:
```

but the first loop, loop A goes on three times, but i don't want b to loop three times, but rather just loop once.

Ok so here's the code I am working with changed a lot so that i don't get in trouble. The basic idea is that I want the else statement to run once instead of the several times it is running due to the range(len(table)):

```
for pair in grouping:
    for row in range(len(table)):
        if pair[0] in ta

        elif pair[0] in [table[row] for table in table] and pair[1] in 
            f] for taair[i])+1)])
        else:  
            for each in pair:
                print(each)
```

Comment: Can you post some code example?

Comment: Take more time to explain what you want to achieve. Show what you have tried. That is, show code. Describe what this code does, as opposed to what you want it to do. If you are doing so, I think people here are willing to help.

Comment: So... don't have your second loop within your first?

Comment: you can use `while` or `if` ?

Comment: If you don't want the `b` loop to go 3 times, why is it nested in the `a` loop?

Comment: I understand youre saying to not put the b loop inside the a loop but i have a condition that if true, needs to run b but if not true, runs a seperate set of loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a conditional here such as

```
for a in A:
    #code
if go==True:    
    for b in b:    
        #do stuff    
    go = False
```

Comment: Is the `if` statement supposed to be nested inside the `a` loop?

Comment: No it's supposed to check if you need to proceed and execute the B loop